# How to learn how to make sentence

Tags: spoken-korean, resources, study-technique

I'm begginner at Korean, I know some vocabulary, how to introduce myself, and some verb but I feel really hard to make a correct sentence in Korean.

All support I find only teach vocabulary, and podcast like TalkToMeInKorean are pretty boring (more for a non native english speaker).

So I wanted to know is there any tips to know how to make you Korean sentence ? am I just trying to go in the wrong way for learning Korean ?

Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly**, just taking your question very literally - if you know some verbs, you already know how to make a Korean sentence, because a Korean sentence can *be* just a verb. Korean is a very 'contextual' language, so you can leave out subjects and objects where they are clear from the context. So simply saying

> 없어요

can mean 'There aren't any', 'I don't have one', 'She isn't here', or possibly some other things depending on context.

**Secondly**, you could make sure that you understand these examples of basic sentence 'types':

something does something (using an action verb):

> Yeongsu sleeps - 영수가 잔다

something is some way (using a descriptive verb):

> The mountain is green - 산이 푸르다

someone does something to something :

> Yongsu reads a book - 영수가 책을 읽는다

something is something:

> He is a Korean.  그는  한국사람이다

something is not something:

> He is not a Korean.  그는 한국사람이 아니다

something becomes something:

> Rain turns to snow.비가  눈이 되다

**Thirdly**, it's good to practice and reinforce vocabulary in a context that helps you remember it. This can be 'real life', but if you don't have a lot of opportunities to speak Korean, a good textbook might have a more cohesive structure than most online resources you can find. https://www.reddit.com/r/Korean/comments/rq3th/the_ultimate_beginners_resource_thread/ has some recommendations for textbooks.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your helpful answer. I will have lot of opportunities to speak Korean because my girlfriend is Korean from Seoul, she can help but I don't want her to be my Teacher. I will keep using other application like "hellotalk" for speaking with korean people. Again thank you for the ressources and your tips !

Comment: @Imnotgood I know what you mean - you don't want every conversation to turn into a grammar lesson! You could keep a little vocabulary and phrase notebook for things you do hear in your Korean conversations though - personally I find that the Korean I've learned from real life is much easier to remember than things learned from books, because it has that personal connection.